# Need to figure out how to show everything that a single user doesn't have

Tags: mysql

I am looking for proper way to say it... I currently have a formula:

```
 SELECT * 
     FROM useritems JOIN (iteminfo) 
         ON (iteminfo.id=useritems.itemid) 
     WHERE active='Y' AND userid!='$userid' 
     ORDER BY itemid DESC LIMIT 40";
```

That is designed to show all the items that a USER (A) does not have.

Suppose USER A has item:
A, B, C, D, E, F,

In theory the formula will show G-Z only...

My problem is that if USER B has Item A, B, C, those items show up in this list because isn't not that USER A has them... USER B has them (therefore it's not user A). How do I keep those items from showing up in USER A's FEED because USER B has them?

Comment: You're not showing everything user A doesn't have. You're showing everything that users OTHER THAN A have.

Comment: I just realized that is my issue...any idea how to bridge that gap?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is get all possible `items` that exist in your `itemInfo` table then find all the ones that `A` doesnt have by using a `LEFT JOIN` and selecting the ones that come out as `NULL`

```
SELECT *
    FROM useritems AS 'u'
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM itemInfo GROUP BY item) AS 'i'
            ON u.id=i.itemid
    WHERE active='Y' AND userid='$userid' AND i.item IS NULL 
    ORDER BY itemid DESC LIMIT 40;
```

Comment: This entry showed nothing where it should have showed me 4 things

Comment: @MikEsy I'm not sure what you're calling your columns. You'll need to edit this post to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

Your query is showing all the items held by users other than A. You can use a subquery to return all the items held by the user, and then exclude them with `NOT IN`.

```
SELECT *
FROM iteminfo
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT itemid
    FROM useritems
    WHERE active = 'Y' AND userid = '$userid'
)
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 40
```

Or the equivalent `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT i.*
FROM iteminfo AS i
LEFT JOIN useritems AS u ON i.id = u.itemid AND u.active = 'Y' AND u.userid = '$userid'
WHERE u.itemid IS NULL
ORDER BY i.id DESC LIMIT 40
```

Comment: Ok that first one worked great! I want to put a DESCENDING ORDER and a LIMIT of 40 items on there...can you help me?  I was getting an error otherwise

Comment: Just add the `ORDER BY` clause to the end of either query. It should be `id`, not `itemid`, because the primary table is `iteminfo`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good case for a left join. I'd do something like:

```
SELECT iteminfo.itemid
FROM iteminfo
LEFT JOIN useritems ON (iteminfo.id=useritems.itemid) AND (useritems.userid = '$userid')
WHERE active='Y' AND userid IS NULL
ORDER BY itemid DESC LIMIT 40";
```

This is assuming that userid is in the useritems table. Left joining on the userid will grab one row for each of the iteminfo entries, and checking whether they're null in the WHERE will give you all iteminfo entries where the userid wasn't a match.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 210 (2nd line)

Comment: Ah, just change the parameters in the SELECT or the type of result you're looking for... I'd modified it to include only the column you want, but it appears you're looking for a boolean. Changing it back to * might or might not fix it, I have no idea what your columns are.